# GQL query by key syntax no longer works in GAE console

Tags: google-app-engine, gql, gqlquery

I have Datastore Viewer URLs stored for specific queries such as:

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE __key__ = key('User',9999)
```

which now, in the updated console interface, don't work. Has the syntax changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the key() function has been changed. It worked for me by removing the single quotes, i.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE __key__ = key(User,9999)
```